# XMLMarshalException when throwing custom WebApplicationException with Jersey 2.5.1

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, moxy, jersey-2.0

I upgraded from Jersey 2.4.1 to 2.5.1 and suddenly have an issue with my error reporting within my code. I apologize for the wall of text, but I figured a well documented question would be beneficial.

Part of my pom.xml:

```
    <!-- Jersey specific information -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, use "jersey-container-servlet-core" -->
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Required only when you are using JAX-RS Client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here are my POJOs:

Abstract

```
package com.mimi.rest.common;

public abstract class AbstractRestStatus
{
    protected int statusCode = 0;
    protected String statusMessage = "OK";
    protected String userMessage = null;
    protected String internalMessage = null;
    protected boolean exception = false;

    // constructors, getters/setters
}
```

Implementation level:

```
package com.mimi.product.rest;

@XmlRootElement(name = "restStatus")
public class RestStatus extends AbstractRestStatus
{
    // constructors, getters/setters

    @Override
    public String getInternalMessage()
    {
        if (!RestConfiguration.INTERNAL_MESSAGES_ENABLED)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return internalMessage;
    }
}
```

Here are the exceptions:

Abstract:

```
package com.mimi.rest.common;

public abstract class AbstractRestException extends WebApplicationException
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private AbstractRestStatus restStatus = null;

    /**
     * Build a rest exception with the provided information to relay to Jersey
     * 
     * @param status
     * @param restStatus
     */
    public AbstractRestException(Status status, AbstractRestStatus restStatus)
    {
        super(Response.status(status).entity(restStatus.asException()).build());
        this.restStatus = restStatus;
    }

    public AbstractRestException(Status status)
    {
        super(Response.status(status).build());
    }

    //restStatus getter
}
```

Impl:

```
package com.mimi.product.rest;

public class RestException extends AbstractRestException
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public RestException(Status status, RestStatus error)
    {
        super(status, error);
    }

    public RestException(Status status)
    {
        super(status);
    }
}
```

My custom resource for debugging:

```
@Path("error")
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML + ";charset=utf-8", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8" })
public String errorGet()
{
    throw new RestException(Status.BAD_REQUEST, new RestStatus(100, "Not allowed", "Whoops, user error"));
}
```

Work and testing done so far:

Doing a `GET` with `Accept: application/json` in 2.4.1 has this (expected) result:

```
{
   "type": "restStatus",
   "exception": true,
   "statusCode": 100,
   "statusMessage": "Not allowed",
   "userMessage": "Whoops, user error"
}
```

Doing the same thing in 2.5.1 has this unexpected result:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-25007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A descriptor for class com.mimi.product.rest.RestStatus was not found in the project.  For JAXB, if the JAXBContext was bootstrapped using TypeMappingInfo[] you must call a marshal method that accepts TypeMappingInfo as an input parameter.
```

- I simply changed the version number in my pom.xml to reproduce this error.
- The issue does not occur when requesting XML
- Adding a @XmlSeeAlso in the abstract does not appear to fix the issue. Due to the nature of how my `AbstractRestStatus` is a shared object between two different products, I'd rather not have to put import statements or have to merge it into a single object as they both implement `getInternalMessage()` differently.

Strangely, if I change my return type in my resource to be `RestStatus` instead of `String`, then the exception thrown will serialize properly in 2.5.1. In both versions, returning a regular `RestStatus` instead of throwing `RestException` will serialize properly, which makes me believe that the issue is more oriented around exceptions than an inheritance issue.

Thank you.

Comment: This is the same issue as https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2325 (will be fixed in 2.6).